# How one javascript event can apply on one different html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm trying to make a jquery mouse event apply on another html page not using php. Is it possible ?

I have for example that:

**Page 1:**

```
<div id="e1"> element 1 </div>
<div id="e2"> element 2 </div>
```

and the Jquery :

```
   $("#e1").hover(function(){
    show.("#o1");
   }); 
   $("#e2").hover(function(){
    show.("#o2");
   });
```

**page 2 :**

```
<div id="o1" style="display:none;"> object 1 </div>
<div id="o2" style="display:none;"> object 2 </div>
```

Thanxxx

Comment: Read up about localStorage or cookies.

Comment: So you want the onclick event to function with elements on a different page? How are you including the second page? Are you using an iframe or do you have both pages open in different tabs? Is it possible for you to post more of your source code to show how you are including page 2 in page 1 please.

Comment: Are you planning to have both pages open at the same time? Otherwise this is impossible. I personally think it will be impossible whatever, but definitely if you are going to only have one page open. It defies the logic.

Comment: yeah, explain how/if the pages are visible at the same time for better answers. Otherwise, refer to PeterKA's comment.

Comment: Hi,  peterKA, i have two different pages for example : page1.html and page2.html both open. I'm trying to make this work at the same time. When the mouse event occurs it apply instantly on the other page. thanx

Comment: create a script file, reference it in both pages

Comment: Yes konkked, that's the first thing i try. But when the mouse event occurs on the first page, nothing happen on the second one, i also try to reload the script from the second page, nothing either.

Comment: One of these pages needs to be the parent and load first.  If you load the 2nd page by dong a window.open from script in your 1st page, then we can probably help you. Otherwise its impossible.

Comment: So, if i want those two pages on different computers, it's impossible ? Even using ajax ?

Comment: Are the two pages open in the same window? Next time use @PeterKA to make sure I am alerted of your answer immediately. If the two pages are not in the same window, you would need to use local storage or cookies and some kind of a trigger on page 2.

Comment: @PeterKA Thanks for you answer. Ideally the two pages are in different computers, in the first you make the action (the mouse event) and in the second one you see the result.

Comment: @comix2000, for that you would need server-side scripting AND some form of server-side storage such as a database.